# Coloring PNG file area if its not transparent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Do You know any good solution (also can be based on canvas), that gives developer ability to change color (fill with hex color) of png image in non-trasparent area (like a mask)? I need transparent area that will change color (or background image), thats why It has to be untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want you need to use `getImageData` and `putImageData` check out [mdn for an explanation on pixel manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas).

Heres some sample code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = document.getElementById("testImage");

canvas.height = canvas.width = 135;
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 135, 135),
    pix = imgd.data,
    newColor = {r:0,g:100,b:200};

for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
    var r = pix[i],
            g = pix[i+1],
            b = pix[i+2];

        if(r == 216 && g == 6 && b == 6){ 
            // Change the red to whatever.
            pix[i] = newColor.r;
            pix[i+1] = newColor.g;
            pix[i+2] = newColor.b;
        }
}

ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);​
```

**[Example demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/BtbSM/)**

With the above code you could check for fuschia by using

`if(r == 255 && g == 0 && b == 255)`

Then just change `newColor` to the replacement color.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pixel manipulation using `<canvas>` raw pixel access

- Read in pixel
- check if it fills the criteria (is not transparent, alpha = 0)
- Replace pixel with solid color

Pixel manipulation resources for `<canvas>` https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Answer (score 1):

You can fill an image/area with the color you want and then paint the png over it.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas API has compositing methods for things like "draw only on pixels that are not transparent in the original image."  This is faster than manipulating the image data and also avoids origin permission issues.

## **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/adg29/pen/RPRdwP) example**

The composite operation you want is `source-in`. The canvas is painted red only where both the red rectangle and the transparent PNG overlap. Everything else is made transparent.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

<a href="javascript:paintNontransparent()">paint non-transparent regions red</a><br>
```

Javascript:

```
var color = '#FF0000';

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var textureURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/LWHZV8v.png';
var textureIMG = new Image();
textureIMG.src = textureURL;

textureIMG.onload = function(){
  canvas.width = textureIMG.width;
  canvas.height = textureIMG.height;        
  ctx.drawImage(textureIMG,0,0);
};


window.paintNontransparent = function() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing)